# Getting blank page in Welcome page

Tags: symfony

Right after the installation, and fixing all the warnings + major problems, I go to the "Welcome" page of Symfony, with so bad luck that the page is empty.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the problems Symfony was complaining about and getting crazy while fixing them I deleted the vendors folder to fix it simply run:

```
php bin/vendors install
```

And you are ready to do some serious programming!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also...
you can try it in development mode like your vhost and then /app_dev.php.

For example:

```
symfony2demo.com/app_dev.php
```

I think this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

A blank page generally means a php error. There could be many reason for this, from damaged installation to wrong files permissions. Or even something simpler like not following all the installation steps. The good news is there should be a clue somewhere in your web server and/or php log files.

The only problem I came across that wasn't necessarily clear from the log files was the insufficient memory limit in `php.ini`. `memory_limit = 32M`. It's unlikely to be the problem from the very start but still worth changing it to 128M or 256M to avoid problems in the future.